# How this list with nested lists is being sorted, in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [10], [5, 6, 7, 8, [10, 20, 30, 40]]]
lst.sort(reverse=True)
print(lst)
```

The output of the above code is,

```
[[10], [5, 6, 7, 8, [10, 20, 30, 40]], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

I wrote this code to see how this list with sub lists is sorted, but seeing the result, I have no clue of how it is being sorted.
Can anyone help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you compare two lists for sorting, it's based on the first element (unless you specify some other `key` function).  So 10, 5, 1.

Comment: @Samwise It also looks at subsequent items if the two it's comparing are equal